# My program to simplify fractions is hitting the call stack limit. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm attempting to do the easy daily programmer on reddit in node.js. Link: https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/4uhqdb/20160725_challenge_277_easy_simplifying_fractions/

I wrote a quick program, yet it's giving the output a bit differently and breaking on the higher ones.

My code:

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

function gcd(a, b) {
  if (b == 0) {
    return a;
  }

  return gcd(b, a & b);
}

function all() {
  rl.question("wewe? ", (answer) => {
    if (answer === "x") {
      rl.close();
      return;
    }
    var str = answer.split(" ");
    var num = +str[0];
    var den = +str[1];
    var div = gcd(num, den);
    console.log(num / div + " " + den / div);
    all();
  });
}

all();
```

This is the current output:

```
aria@aria-ubuntu /development/randomcode/dailyprogramming$ node Simplifying\ fractions.js
wewe? 4 8
0.5 1
wewe? 1536 78360
readline.js:924
            throw err;
            ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at gcd (/development/randomcode/dailyprogramming/Simplifying fractions.js:7:13)
    at gcd (/development/randomcode/dailyprogramming/Simplifying fractions.js:12:10)
    at gcd (/development/randomcode/dailyprogramming/Simplifying fractions.js:12:10)
    at gcd (/development/randomcode/dailyprogramming/Simplifying fractions.js:12:10)
    at gcd (/development/randomcode/dailyprogramming/Simplifying fractions.js:12:10)
    at gcd (/development/randomcode/dailyprogramming/Simplifying fractions.js:12:10)
    at gcd (/development/randomcode/dailyprogramming/Simplifying fractions.js:12:10)
    at gcd (/development/randomcode/dailyprogramming/Simplifying fractions.js:12:10)
    at gcd (/development/randomcode/dailyprogramming/Simplifying fractions.js:12:10)
    at gcd (/development/randomcode/dailyprogramming/Simplifying fractions.js:12:10)
```

Expected output:

```
1 2
64 3265
```

Comment: You will know why if you put a `console.log` call inside your `gcd` function.

Comment: it appears to get stuck on 512 512

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple mistype! Damn my new keyboard. I can't believe I did this.

I used 4 & 8 when it was supposed to be 4 % 8.

Comment: It happens to us all!

Comment: its 1am! :( don't blame me :p